# Matching double quotes in the following array of arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex

This is the array of arrays:

```
[ 'markdown',
  [ 'para', 'This is a ', [ 'em', 'test' ] ],
  [ 'hr' ],
  [ 'para', {class: 'noind'}, 'another test' ],
  [ 'para', '"test with double quotes"' ],
```

I know how to match `para`s:

```
for (i = 1; i < jsonml.length; i++) {
  if (jsonml[i][0] === 'para') {
    // do stuff
  }
}
```

Now I want to match only the `para`s that have double quotes (`[ para, '"test with double quotes"' ]`).

I tried this:

```
if (jsonml[i][0] === 'para' && jsonml[i][1].match(/"/g)) {
```

But I get `TypeError: Cannot call method 'match' of undefined`. Maybe because of `[hr]` or `[ 'para', {class: 'noind'}, 'another test' ]`? If so, how can I make the code work?

Comment: You are getting this error because some of your arrays have only 1 element.

Comment: Check the generic utility method in my answer which can detect double quotes in nested array @alexchenco

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**JSBIN DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/magikodeno/1/edit?js,console)

Simple utility method to find string with double quotes within nested array:

```
   var array = [ 'ma"r"kdown', [ 'para', 'This is a ', ['em', 'test']],
      [ 'hr' ],
      [ 'para', {class: 'noind'}, 'another test' ],
      [ 'para', '"test with double quotes"' ]];

    function checkDoubleQuotes(array) {
      array.forEach(function(value) {
        if({}.toString.call(value)==="[object Array]") {
           return checkDoubleQuotes(value); 
        }
        if(typeof value==='string' && value.match(/"/g)) {
          console.log("matched : "+value);
        }

      })
    }

    checkDoubleQuotes(array);
```

Answer (score 1):

You will have to test if the value is a string before using `.match()` on it.

```
if (jsonml[i][0] === 'para' && typeof jsonml[i][1] === "string" && jsonml[i][1].match(/"/g)) {
```

Some of your `jsonml[i][1]` values either don't exist or are not a string, thus they wouldn't have a `.match()` method and then you get that exception.